# Google Apps append footer email signature

Tags: google-apps

I've tried to use "Append Footer" function in Google Apps to create a standard footer for every employee of the company. The general guidance to do this is here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2364576

But no guidance as to how I can use HTML tags that will automatically pull username, telephone, email, company name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several 3rd parties application integrate into Google Apps.

e.g.https://www.signaturesatori.com/ or try Google Search